# Usage relating to a new word

Tags: word-usage

I have often heard people use the word "paramount" to mean "the most important", which I think is correct usage.

However, I have also heard them use "parmountacy" or "paramountcy".

e.g. The changes we are making establishes the paramountacy of international law in these cases.

I am wondering if there is such a word as "paramountacy"?

Comment: This question can be improved by adding the results of your own research. That is basic site etiquette. A good starting point is *OneLook*, which will check many dictionaries for the word in question. You may find http://onelook.com/?w=paramountcy&ls=a and http://onelook.com/?w=paramountacy&ls=a helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The OED recognizes both *paramountship* and *paramountcy* (going back to the 17th century), but not *paramountacy*, which would be an irregular, not to say peculiar formation (which does not, of course, mean it can't be created).  You say you 'heard' the word; might it be an unusual pronunciation of *paramountcy*?

Comment: I think more likely OP has either misheard or he's listening to people thinking of/trying to say [preeminency](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preeminency). Not a word I like much (plain *pre-eminence* seems fine to me), but it *is* used.